# Performance of User Defined Function in R

Tags: r, function, parameters

I'm writing a user defined function that accepts 10 parameters and 2 data vectors. The 2 data vectors can get pretty big (10K+ data points) and the function does a lot of mathematical computations and requires to often look up the values of the parameters passed to the function.
Does it make any difference in terms of speed of my code whether I write:

`my.intensity=function(params, eval.times, event.times) {`

`s<-sort(eval.times)`

`t<-sort(event.times)`

`par1<-params[1]`

`par2<-params[2]`

`par3<-params[3]`

`...`

`par10<-params[10]`

and then use `par1`, `par2`, ... , `par10` in my function or whether I just use `params[1]`
`params[2]`
`params[3]`
`...`
`params[10]`, making the function lookup the values each time?

Comment: Have you tried `system.time()`? It's probably faster to have 10 parameters than make the function look at the values each time. But at that point you may need to consider how easy it is to go back and edit your code compared with the – probably unsubstantial – time gains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the gain is insignificant. Go with what makes more sense programmatically. More likely, you'll want the 10 arguments grouped together so they're easier to call and manipulate.

From this test, it looks like having 10 parameters is slightly faster. In this simple case the gain is really only marginal (~2%), so you won't need to worry about it as long as your function isn't written horribly.

```
myfun1 <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10) {
  a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10
}

myfun2 <- function(a) {
  a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] + a[10]
}

x1 <- as.list(rnorm(10))
x2 <- list(rnorm(10))

> system.time(for (i in seq_len(1e6)) do.call(myfun1, x1))
   user  system elapsed 
   5.97    0.00    6.00 
> system.time(for (i in seq_len(1e6)) do.call(myfun2, x2))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.11    0.00    6.11
```

In general, it is faster to look up by variable than to look up by index. Since this was a very basic operation and there was a nearly insignificant gain, given a complex operation the gain wouldn't be measurable.

Comment: +1 but let's put these results into their context. Your functions are doing nothing else than a trivial operation and you can hardly see a difference: 0.11 microseconds out of a 6 microseconds per function call! While the OP said his function does a lot of mathematical computations. So the answer the OP is looking for is "no, no significant difference". And by the way, you did not test exactly what the OP was describing. But I think the result would be the same, no significant difference.

Comment: I thought my analysis after the test explained that sufficiently. Without his use case, we can't know for sure. Lookup appears to be 2% of an addition function, so unless the function is horribly designed (nested loops, referencing same values by index in the smallest loop), the speed up is insignificant.

Comment: "You may not need", "it is impossible for us to know", "test for yourself", "we can't know for sure"... You could be a little more convincing!